# VBS - отправка на FTP

Tags: ftp, visual-basic

Здравствуйте. Необходимо отправить целую папку или файлы определённого типа, из определённой папки с подпапками, по e-mail или FTP из VBS файла. Перерыл весь Интернет, так и не нашёл, кроме тех скриптов, которые действительно работают, но увы, с конкретным файлом. Также имя отправляемого файла по e-mail или FTP мне не может быть известно, поэтому ищу скрипт, который сможет без разбора отправлять файлы из папки с подпапками по e-mail или FTP.

Помогите, пожалуйста! Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `скриптов, которые действительно работают, но увы, с конкретным файлом.` Теперь ещё найдите код перебора файлов каталога (не включая или включая подкаталоги) - и объедините.

Comment: Ага, ясно. Конечно, возникла идея архивирования папки, но нужно сделать так, чтобы сам процесс архивации был замечен не был. Есть ключ -ibck WInRAR, но он высвечивает иконку на панели задач. Есть ли решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ага, ясно. Конечно, возникла идея архивирования папки, но нужно сделать так, чтобы сам процесс архивации был замечен не был. Есть ключ -ibck WInRAR, но он высвечивает иконку на панели задач. Есть ли решение?

Можно использовать средства Windows, еще Windows XP имела встроенную поддержку ZIP-архивов. Код ниже добавит файлы в папку программно, без какого-либо информирования пользователя.

```
    Dim fs, wsh, sh, file_to_zip
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set sh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set file_to_zip = fs.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\User\Desktop\for_testing.zip")
    ' This line writes a zip file header to the TextStream object:
    file_to_zip.Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, Chr(0))
    file_to_zip.Close
    ' This line creates the zip archive:
    sh.NameSpace("C:\Users\User\Desktop\for_testing.zip").CopyHere "C:\Users\User\Desktop\for_testing"
```